# SessionRegistery in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, session, java-security

I have problem with session invalidation in spring. When user execute the following logout code

```
                sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessionId).expireNow();
                sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionId);
                request.getSession().invalidate();
```

it works fine and user removed from sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals(); list.

But user auto logout after specific time set in  web.xml. sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals(); still shows that user.

```
    <session-config>  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout></session-config>
```

Any Clue ?

Comment: Why are you hacking around those things yourself? Spring Security already handles those... Even the timeout. Make sure you registered the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` and don't mess around with the logout yourself let Spring Security handle it for you. (It does already everything you coded up yourself).